# Characterizing polynomials which behave like a logarithm modulo $1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, characters

This is a version of a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4284968/255320) I asked in Math StackExchange about two weeks ago, which is still unanswered. (**UPDATE:** the original question for $R=\mathbb{Z}$ has been finally answered, but its generalization to other $R$ is still open, see the edit below).

Fixing a prime $p$, consider the abelian group $\Psi$ of logarithmic homomorphisms $\pi: \mathbb{Z}\setminus p\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ that are quotients of polynomial functions $\mathbb{Z}\setminus p\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$. Equivalently, an element $\pi \in \Psi$ can be identified with an equivalence class of polynomials $P \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that the following condition

$$P(ab) = P(a) + P(b) \pmod 1$$

holds for all integers $a, b$ coprime to $p$. Two polynomials belong to the same equivalence class if they induce the same homomorphism in $\Psi$. I will make this identification implicitly in what follows.

The group $\Psi_0$ spanned by polynomials of the form $P_N(x)=\frac{x^N-1}{\Delta_N^2}$, where $\Delta_N = \gcd\limits_{a \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus p\mathbb{Z}} (a^N-1)$, is easily seen to be a subgroup of $\Psi$, by an argument similar to the one in [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3330375/formal-proofs-for-f-pa-cdot-b-f-pa-f-pb-mod-p/3331280#3331280). If I'm not mistaken, $\Psi_0$ can be described explicitly in terms of generators and relations as follows: we take as generators $g_r=P_{(p-1)p^r}$ for $r\ge 0$, with the relations

- $p g_0 = 0$,
- $p^2 g_{r+1} = p g_r$ if either $r>0$ or $p\neq 2$ or both,
- $8 g_1 = 0$ if $p=2$.

The denominators of the generator polynomials can also be calculated explicitly: we have $\Delta_{(p-1)p^r} = p^{r+1}$ unless $p=2$ and $r>0$, in which case it equals $p^{r+2}$.

Note that using the isomorphism between $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ and the group of roots of unity $\mu_\infty$, one can also think of elements of $\Psi$ and $\Psi_0$ as Dirichlet characters, which was in fact the original motivation for my question; for instance, $g_r$ corresponds to a character of modulus $p^{-r} \Delta_{(p-1)p^r}^2$ and order $\Delta_{(p-1)p^r}$ (hence the images of all elements of $\Psi_0$ lie inside the Prüfer $p$-group).

---

My question is the following:

> **Do we have $\Psi = \Psi_0$?**

In the linked original question, I tried to see if I could express any polynomial from $\Psi$ directly as an integral linear combination of $P_N$, but this strategy failed because there are non-integral linear combinations of $P_N$ that belong to $\Psi$; however, all of the examples I found also turn out to be in $\Psi_0$. For example, if $p=3$, the polynomial $\frac{1}{2} (P_1+P_2)$ is in the same equivalence class as $-P_2=-g_1$, and if $p=2$, $\frac{1}{12} (P_3-P_1)$ is equivalent to $4 P_2 = 4 g_1$.

---

More generally, for an order $R$ in a global field and an ideal $\mathfrak{p}$, we can consider the composition of its canonical multiplicative norm function $| \cdot | : R \to \mathbb{Z}$ with polynomial functions $\mathbb{Z}\setminus \mathfrak{p} \to \mathbb{Q}$, and quotient out to obtain the abelian group $\Psi^{(R)}$. We can again define $\Psi^{(R)}_0$ as the subgroup spanned by "norm-polynomials" of the form $P^{(R)}_N(x)=\frac{|x|^N-1}{(\Delta^{(R)}_N)^2}$, where $\Delta^{(R)}_N = \gcd\limits_{a \in R\setminus \mathfrak{p}} (|a|^N-1)$.

Is $\Psi^{(R)} = \Psi^{(R)}_0$ in this more general case? If not, is it possible to obtain an explicit presentation of $\Psi^{(R)}$ in terms of generators and relations?

---

**EDIT:** I have found a positive answer to the original question for $R=\mathbb{Z}$. Since it's elementary I've posted it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4311427/255320) (the key was realizing that the relation $p^2 g_{r+1} = p g_r$ could be refined to $p g_{r+1} = g_r$ in the odd case; then one can use the fact that $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is cyclic to prove the statement inductively). However, this answer isn't entirely satisfying to me, since I can't see a way to generalize it to other rings such as $\mathbb{F}_p[t]$, so I've decided to leave this question up in the hope that someone can find a better proof that works uniformly for all $R$.

In fact, one could generalize the problem even more by considering polynomial functions $\Xi \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, where $\Xi$ is any multiplicatively closed set of integers. The sets $\Psi$, $\Psi_0$ and the numbers $\Delta_N$ can be defined in the obvious way. This version of the problem includes the previous version for global fields as a special case, by taking $\Xi$ to be the image of the norm function applied to the set of elements of $R$ coprime to $\mathfrak{p}$.